# Select a specific cell in a range with EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to select a specific cell in a named range. I would like to select a specific cell via excel formula. As an example let's say I have a range that included 3 cells containing the three values : House, Hotel, Cottage. The range name is Homes. Is there a way to write in excel formula "=Homes(1,1)" to get the value "House" or something like that. I know how to do that in VBA but I don't want to use this kind of stuff for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is the "INDEX" function.

```
=INDEX(Homes,1,1)
```